# How to set up a usb flash drive that has NOTHING on it

Tags: usb-flash-drive

So I'm sure I did something stupid...I deleted everything off of my usb flash drive, rewriting it with zeros (as Ubuntu stated). I can see the device in "disks" on Ubuntu, but it does not show up in OS X Yosemite. In Ubuntu, the only option I have in the "disks" application is "mount options". I am guessing I need to set up my flash drive somehow, but I have no idea where to begin. How do I get my flash drive to a state where it can store files again?

My particular flash drive is a LaCie RuggedKey. I am using Ubuntu and OS X, and I have access to Windows 7 and 8, so suggestions for any operating system is fine.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware tech support. That being said, you probably nuked the partitions on the drive, making it utterly blank.

Comment: Reformat it using [disk utility OS X](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201639) or [disk utility Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/476589/format-disk-in-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up your drive in a way, that it is compatible with both Ubuntu and OSX I recommend you use the OSX Disk Utility.

In Disk Utility the drive will show up on the left hand side (even if it does not show up in finder), where you can chose it, then select "partition". Use a MBR partition table and a HFS+ non-journalled format for best compatibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see the drive in OS X Disk Utility. My OS X system does not recognize the drive in any way, even when I type "diskutil list" into the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When you overwrite the data on your USB with zeroes you have to setup a filesystem that can be read by the operating of your choice. NTFS is readable by most operating systems, but you can also use Fat32. So you can actually use gParted through Ubuntu and set up an NTFS/Fat32 partition on it. I personally use Fat32 for USBs.

gParted is a GUI application, and is very intuitive to use. To change data, ensure you are on the right device. Right click the partition, unmount it, then set up a new partition as always. Hope this helps!

Comment: The flash drive is not seen by OS X in any way. When I am running Ubuntu, the usb appears in the disk utility menu, but all formatting options are unavailable. The only option is "mount options". I tried gParted before making this post, but gParted did not list the drive. Is there a way to manually mount it? When I type "lsusb" into the terminal, I can see the flash drive. I am not sure what the issue is that prevents formatting as I normally would.

Comment: Using /dev/zero implies you manually placed data into it using the command 'dd'. Otherwise, there's no need to use /dev/zero at all. You need a filesystem on the USB otherwise it can't be read. Trying this from Ubuntu, use this command on your USB to erase all data completely: dd count=1 bs=512 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX && sync You should be using the location of the usb instead of sdX. E.g. if your USB is on /dev/sdb then use that intstead of /dev/sdX.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have given this a try, running that line of code with sudo. I get this response "dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb'". I am assuming sdb given the USB location as it is missing from dev when the USB is disconnected.

Comment: If your USB cannot be  allocated under /dev then it's possible your USB is broken. When you wipe data on it it should still be recognised by the operating system, just not writable yet. What have you been doing to your USB before overwriting the data with /dev/zero? If you wanted to delete data, you just delete the folders; and if you want it ultimately gone then it's better to just format it under the same partition type. Can I see the Ubuntu article that suggested you overwrite the USB with /dev/zero?

Comment: I have not been using my USB to do much. Prior to wiping it, it held an image of Ubuntu that could be used to boot Ubuntu. I did not read any article, unfortunately. I saw an option to write the USB with zeros to clear it out. I did not realize I was doing anything hazardous to the hardware. One thing I find strange is Disk Utility can see it, but only gives mounting options. Another strange observation, when I type lsusb into terminal, the device is seen and is still recognized to be a LaCie product.

Comment: I guess my problem right now is how do I mount it? Disk Utility has manual mounting options, but I do not know how to get it to mount.